# Cordova: How to move file to the Download folder?

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, cordova-plugins, quasar-framework

**THE SITUATION:**

In my mobile app I need to download a file and store in the Download folder.

The download part is working fine.
The file is properly downloaded from the server and stored in the following folder:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.cordova.MY_APP_NAME.app/my_file.pdf
```

But the location is not really user-friendly.

To access it I have to go to: *Internal storage / Android / data / org.cordova.MY_APP_NAME.app /*

So I need to move it to the main Download folder.

The file transfer is what I don't manage to do.

I know that there are already several similar questions on SO.

I have tried them all but none really worked for me, I could never see the file in the actual Download folder.

**PROJECT INFO:**

I am using [Quasar](http://quasar-framework.org/) with [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) and [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/).

**PLATFORM**:

For the moment I am working with Android. But ideally I am looking for a solution that works for both Android and IOS.

**THE CODE:**

**The download code:**

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer() // eslint-disable-line
var uri = encodeURI('https://MY_SERVER_PATH')

fileTransfer.download(
  uri,
  cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory + 'my_file.pdf',
  entry => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL())
    this.moveFile(entry.toURL())
  },
  error => {
    console.log('download error source ' + error.source)
    console.log('download error target ' + error.target)
    console.log('download error code' + error.code)
  },
  false,
  {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic asdasdasdasdassdasdasd'
    }
  }
)
```

**The File transfer code:**

```
moveFile(fileUri) {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
    fileUri,
    fileEntry => {
      let newFileUri = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download'

      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
        newFileUri,
        dirEntry => {
          fileEntry.moveTo(dirEntry, 'new_filename.pdf', this.moveFileSuccess, this.moveFileError)
        },
        this.moveFileError)
    },
    this.moveFileError)
},
moveFileSuccess(entry) {
  console.log('file move success')
  console.log(entry)
},
moveFileError(error) {
  console.log('file move error')
  console.log(error)
}
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I move a file to the Download folder?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

This is the console log of the `cordova.file` object:

```
applicationDirectory: "file:///android_asset/"
applicationStorageDirectory: "file:///data/user/0/org.cordova.MY_APP_NAME.app/"
cacheDirectory:"file:///data/user/0/org.cordova.MY_APP_NAME.app/cache/"
dataDirectory: "file:///data/user/0/org.cordova.MY_APP_NAME.app/files/"
documentsDirectory: null
externalApplicationStorageDirectory: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.cordova.MY_APP_NAME.app/"
externalCacheDirectory: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.cordova.MY_APP_NAME.app/cache/"
externalDataDirectory: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.cordova.MY_APP_NAME.app/files/"
externalRootDirectory: "file:///storage/emulated/0/"
sharedDirectory: null
syncedDataDirectory: null
tempDirectory: null
```

Comment: What is wrong with the file transfer code? You should report all errors and exceptions of course. You let us guess now.

Comment: `cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory`. Just try a different directory. The one that for the downloads/

Comment: You are right. It gives error code 1. I have been trying other locations, but it gives the same error, or it just doesn't save it. What should be the exact path of the Download folder?

Comment: Dont put a hard coded path (well a hard coded path you could find with a file explorer app on your device of course so why do you ask? But as said before dont use `cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory. Just try a different directory. `.

Comment: `externalRootDirectory: "file:///storage/emulated/0/"` That one you should use. And the full path of the Download directory is `/storage/emulated/0/Download`. Dont tell us that it is not already there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay I managed to resolve it.

- First of all is totally unnecessary to download and then move the file. It can just be directly downloaded in the desired direction.
- The correct path (in my case) was this:

  `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'download/' + 'my_file.pdf`

  that correspond to: `file:///storage/emulated/0/download/my_file.pdf`

  and that means that to find the file inside the device you have to go to: Internal Storage / Download / my_file.pdf
- Add the following value in the config.xml:

  `<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
  <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,root" />`
- It's important to check for permission using this cordova plugin: [cordova-plugin-android-permissions](https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions)

You can make a quick test like this:

```
let permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions
permissions.checkPermission(permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, checkPermissionCallback, null)

function checkPermissionCallback(status) {
  console.log('checking permissions')
  console.log(status)
}
```

Most probably the result is `false`. And that means that we have to request permission to the user:

```
permissions.requestPermission(successCallback, errorCallback, permission)
```

In this way it will appear the alert asking for permission.

**THE CODE:**

To put it all together, this is the working code:

```
let pdfPath = 'https://MY_SERVER_PATH'

let permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions
permissions.checkPermission(permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, checkPermissionCallback, null)

// Checking for permissions
function checkPermissionCallback(status) {
  console.log('checking permissions')
  console.log(status)
  if (!status.hasPermission) {
    var errorCallback = function () {
      console.warn('Storage permission is not turned on')
    }
    // Asking permission to the user
    permissions.requestPermission(
      permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      function (status) {
        if (!status.hasPermission) {
          errorCallback()
        } else {
          // proceed with downloading
          downloadFile()
        }
      },
      errorCallback)
  } else {
    downloadFile()
  }
}

function downloadFile() {
  let filePath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'download/' + 'my_file.pdf'
  let fileTransfer = new window.FileTransfer()
  let uri = encodeURI(decodeURIComponent(pdfPath))

  // Downloading the file
  fileTransfer.download(uri, filePath,
    function (entry) {
      console.log('Successfully downloaded file, full path is ' + entry.fullPath)
      console.log(entry)
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log('error')
      console.log(error)
    },
    false
  )
}
```

Comment: is the "download" case sensitive, as in my device, it is "Download" (capital D)?

Comment: @FrancescoMussi. Could you, please, take a look at this question and help if you can because I'm not sure where should I put the code you wrote? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312863/how-to-download-calendar-file-ics-to-mobile-phone-android

Comment: This is a solution for Android, but how did you get this to work for iOS?  The `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` and the `cordova.file.dataDirectory` are both paths that you can write to in iOS, but they are app sub-folders, which means the user can't access them via iPhones `Files` app.  How can we get files to the users general `Downloads` folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer() // eslint-disable-line
var uri = encodeURI('https://MY_SERVER_PATH')
var fileURL =  "///storage/emulated/0/Download";

fileTransfer.download(
  uri,
  fileURL+ 'your_file.pdf',
  entry => {
            console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL())
            this.moveFile(entry.toURL())
           },
  error => {
            console.log('download error source ' + error.source)
            console.log('download error target ' + error.target)
            console.log('download error code' + error.code)
           },
      false,
      {
       headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Basic asdasdasdasdassdasdasd'
      }
    }
 )
```

you can directly save downloaded file to your path

Try above code and let me know if its work.

Comment: In this way the download fails with the error code 1

Comment: can you share your server path

Comment: + 'my_file.pdf'

Comment: fileTransfer.download(
  uri,
  fileURL+ 'my_file.pdf',
  entry =>                                               try like this brother

Comment: `In this way the download fails with the error code 1` Well.... what does `1`mean? Should we know?

Comment: Error code 1 should be NOT_FOUND_ERR: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#list-of-error-codes-and-meanings

Answer (score -1):

```
 cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory.
```

For that path you do not need to request any permission in manifest or require any permission at all.

But for others like external storage and so you need them.

You are #1244 with this problem this year.

Google for runtime permissions.

You can than directly download to the Download directory.

Comment: I know there are many similar question. And there will be more if no actual answer is provided... If you can please paste some working code we can all have some closure :)

Comment: By the way I have edited the question adding the console.log of the cordova.file object, that include file locations, but it doesn't seem to be there the Download folder..

Comment: `I know there are many similar question.` Not that i know of for Xamarin. But the problem is well known. Now did you google? You are confirming or denying nothing .

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to be there the Download folder.` Well than create it. What is the problem? And you said you wanted to transfer to that folder. So what is going on? Pretty unclear.

Comment: Please post the file locations as text. I wanted to copy/paste one but you made it impossible. Should i type it in or what?

Comment: I paste it as text. About the destination folder. I need to move (or just download) the file in one folder where the user can find it. It can be the Downloads folder or the Documents folder. Somewhere where it can be easily located. And avoid the user to go to look for the file here: Internal storage / Android / data / org.cordova.MY_APP_NAME.app /

Comment: I was reply to your comment. You said it was Pretty unclear. So I was making as clear as possible. In any case is not necessary to be rude.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19353934)

Comment: @Cindy Meister, Of course it was an answer. And to the point too. Read the other answer of OP and you know. It seems that you did not understand the question.