# saving file to /storage/emulated/0/Download/ instead of Download folder

Tags: android, android-external-storage

i download a file with download manager, and set the destination of file with path given from this code:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
```

but the file saves in:

> /storage/emulated/0/Download/

not in Download Folder itself.

i have read that Download folder is a link for actual folder `/storage/emulated/0/Download/`, but the file downloaded is just in this path:
`/storage/emulated/0/Download/` and not in `Download` folder!

How can i download my file exactly on **Download folder**?

Comment: "but the file saves in: `/storage/emulated/0/Download/` not in Download Folder itself" -- that *is* the "Download Folder itself", if by "the Download Folder itself" you mean the `Download/` directory seen in file managers.

Comment: @CommonsWare i want it to be saved on Download/ directory seen in file managers. but now its saving on  /storage/emulated/0/Download/

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Download/` **is** the `Download/` directory seen in file managers. `/storage/emulated/0/` is a typical location for the root of what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). External storage is what you see in an on-device file manager, and external storage is what you see on a desktop OS when you attach your device using a USB cable.

Comment: @CommonsWare but im see both of these directories with diffrent content in my android file manager!

Comment: Then update your question with a [mcve] showing how you are downloading this file.

Comment: Hi All, is there any update about solution of above question? I am having similar issue and looking forward for solution/suggestion.

Comment: Just FYI. I resolved similar situation by using this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49689385/cordova-how-to-move-file-to-the-download-folder